# How to use expression inside *ngfor?

Tags: angular

I have one iterating array and i have to sort based on the selection,i have bind the sortby with ngModel using expression,but it seems some template parsing error,What is the proper way to accomplish the same?

**app.html**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Sort By</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="sort">
    <ion-option value="name">Name</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="stall">Stall Number</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="plan">Plan</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item item-detail *ngFor="let exhibit of exhibits | sortBy :'{{sort}}';  
let i = index" name="exhibit">
  <h2>{{ exhibit.name }}</h2>
  <h5>{{ exhibit.plan }}</h5>
  <h5>{{ exhibit.link }}</h5>
  <h5>{{ exhibit.stall }}</h5>
  <h5>{{ exhibit.description }}</h5>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `{{}}`(lead to syntax error) and `''`(lead to static string **sort**).

If the variable `sort` comes from component, you can use it directly at `ngFor` expression like below:

```
<ion-item item-detail *ngFor="let exhibit of exhibits | sortBy:sort; let i = index" name="exhibit">
  ...
</ion-item>``
```